# Detect HTTP sessions using tcpdump

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I have a tracefile and I want to ﬁnd all web servers that were successfully visited in the trace, contacted via HTTP.

I'm using:

```
tcpdump -r file.trace - tcp  port 80
```

Maybe I have to search for a list of server IP that send response packets to me (I mean those that create HTTP sessions with me). Just servers, not other TCP connections. I mean, I need server IPs that answer to HTTP requests and send HTTP responses back.

How could I do that?

Comment: If it's easier to use a GUI, remember that many tools can read these capture files, including [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: @RichHomolka yes i know that but i need tcpdump.

Comment: I don't understand your remark about removing the hyphen.  How is it failing if you take it out?

Comment: i want to ﬁnd all web servers that were successfully visited in the trace (that is, contacted via HTTP).
Include any servers that engaged in a valid instance of the HTTP protocol, even if the status code returned
was, for example, 404 rather than 200.

Comment: The question remains: _how_ is it failing?

Comment: @Scott command is working but i think i need some other commands to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tcpdump -r file.trace - tcp dst port 80
```

is, as you've discovered, not a valid tcpdump command.  If you remove the extra `-`, then you get

```
tcpdump -r file.trace tcp dst port 80
```

which is a valid tcpdump command, that will show you only traffic *to* TCP port 80.  It will not show you traffic *from* TCP port 80, so, for example, if `file.trace` has HTTP traffic to and from port 80, it will show you HTTP request traffic but ***NOT*** HTTP response traffic.

If you want to see traffic to *and* from port 80, use

```
tcpdump -r file.trace tcp port 80
```

However, if there's TCP traffic other than HTTP traffic to or from port 80, that will also be shown.

In addition, HTTP traffic *not* going to or from port 80, such as HTTP-over-SSL/TLS ("https") traffic, or traffic to ports such as port 8080, will not be shown.  To, for example, see traffic to or from port 80 (for HTTP) and port 443 (for HTTPS), do

```
tcpdump -r file.trace tcp port 80 or 443
```

So what's "not working"?

Is it not showing, for example, HTTPS traffic?  If so, you need to add port 443.

Is it not showing traffic to other ports?  If so, you need to add those ports as well.  Tcpdump can't recognize HTTP traffic (and Wireshark only recognizes it by port number).

Is it showing only requests, not responses?  If you want to see responses, use `tcp port` rather than `tcp dst port`.  If you *only* want to see requests, use `tcp dst port`.

Comment: tnx for your answer but i want to get list of servers ips that send response packets to me(i mean those that create HTTP sessions with me). i mean just servers not other TCPconnections.how could i done that?

Comment: i mean i need server IPs that answer to http request and send http response back.write this ips in file

Comment: And what's the problem?  This has nothing to do with the tcdump command, it's working as designed.  Your problem is obviously post-processing the data ...

Comment: I.e., tcpdump is not designed to show you lists of IP addresses, it's designed to show you dissections of packets.  If you want to turn those into lists of IP addresses, you need to process the output of tcpdump, or use some other tool.

Comment: @GuyHarris ok well.and how i can detect valid http sessions?

Comment: Define "valid".  If you mean you want to check whether a packet with a *source* TCP port of 80 (an HTTP response would typically have a *source* port of 80, not a *destination* port of 80) is part of an HTTP reply, you'd have to have your own program look at the text of the reply, or run tcpdump with the -x flag and parse that output.  For HTTPS, that's harder, as you'd have to decrypt the SSL/TLS traffic and see if it's HTTP traffic....

Comment: @GuyHarris iv run tcpdump with - w - tcp src port 80 and pipe it to string but the problem still remain.for example why this statement cannot be true: if servers(packets that have source port 80) reply this mean the session is established.(because ehen i use this command with src instead of dst iv just get 4 website but using dst almost 20 :(